# Switching between fragments does not call onStop method

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar

[see my application view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVYPr.png)

I have 3 Fragments that I switch between with three `Toolbar` buttons. When I go from **1st** fragment to **2nd** fragment `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods are not called and android sees that fragment as still running I guess, but when I go from **1st** fragment to **3rd**, they are called. I want it to be called when I go from **1st** to **2nd** one, so I can call onResume() function when I go back to **1st** fragment, so I can trigger some functions. What causes it and how can I solve?

Comment: Can you post your code? Especially the part you switch between fragments

Comment: Change your OffscreenPageLimit  to 1.Viewpager is suppose to do that.

Comment: that's how adapter works. It is an expected behavior. Fragments on right and left are not destroyed. They are just out of screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are fragments inside ViewPager. so, on stop or onpause wont call
there is a interface in fragment named as

```
    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

using this method u can get to know the visibility of fragment 
else you can use the setOffscreenPageLimit(value);
example

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Fragment's LifeCycle methods( **onPause()** and **onStop()** etc.) Dependent on Activity's Life cycle Methods.

It means if your Activity's **onPause()** and **onStop()** called then your fragment's **onPause()** and **onStop()** will be called

If you want to notify your fragment that it is visible or not then you can use.

Override this method in your fragments.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) 
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (visible)
    {
         // Control will be here if fragment is visible.
         //Do whatever you want.
    }
}
```